# Recursive CMD or BAT Windows Script

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, command-line-interface, powershell, windows-command-prompt

How can I create a BAT or CMD which will iterate through a folder tree and run same command agaists each folder file?

E.g

```
myexe.exe C:\Documents and Settings\folder1\filename.txt
myexe.exe C:\Documents and Settings\folder2\filename.txt
```

Notes:

- The filename is the same on each folder found.
- The folder names will be all different.

Your help is very appreciated or any hints of where to start.

Comment: is powershell an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapt this batch file to your needs:

```
@echo off
cd "\program files"
for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%a in (`dir filename.txt /s/b`) do (
        echo %%a
        myexe "%%a"
)
```

make sure to wrap the variable in double quotes in case the file name has spaces in it.

Comment: '+1'. Would have been my own answer, but without the nice formatting of the loop. Now I've learned how+where to make line breaks without these ugly '^'-chars from your answer. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

A PowerShell approach:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse . FILENAME.TXT | foreach {
    $_
    & myexe $_
}
```